# read c++ bytes bitfields in java

Tags: java, c++, byte, bit-fields

I have some legacy system that produces bytes[] array using bitfields in C++ that will sent over the network

```
struct date_compressed { 
    unsigned int d:5;  //2 bytes
    unsigned int m:4; //1 bytes
    unsigned int y;   //4 bytes
}; 

This produces a hex string of 9fd3d46fde070000
```

I need to able to read these bytes in Java and read the proper value , how do i do that?

I am looking at few ByteBuf library like netty etc but i cant find any good example how do we do this.

Thanks

Comment: Your hex string makes no sense. It is 8 bytes long, so looks zero-padded, and that's ok, we can ignore the last four 0's in the hex string, but it has 30 bits set. That is way too many, since a year value wouldn't need more than 12 bits, and 5 + 4 + 12 = 21 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), and make sure to set the endianness correctly.

*Example*

```
byte[] data = new byte[7];
// fill data here

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int d = buf.getShort() & 0x1f; // 2 bytes, 5 bits, unsigned
int m = buf.get() & 0xf;       // 1 byte, 4 bits, unsigned
int y = buf.getInt();          // 4 bytes, 32 bits, signed
```

Sure, the year value is signed, not unsigned like the C++ code specified, but you won't have year values that big.

Comment: for testing purposes i change my struct as follow
`

-- C++
struct date_compressed { 
    unsigned int d:5;  //2 bytes
    unsigned int m:5;  //2 bytes
    unsigned int y;   //4 bytes
};

struct date_compressed dt2 = { 23, 06, 2015 }; 
 
 
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(dataBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int d = buf.getShort() & 0x1f; // 2 bytes, 5 bits, unsigned
int m = buf.getShort() & 0xf;       // 2 bytes, 5 bits, unsigned
int y = buf.getInt();          // 4 bytes, 32 bits, signed
  
But this print 23 / 04 /2015

`
Any idea ? thx

Comment: @willy To research what is going on, examine the raw bytes directly, both the `date_compressed` in C++ and the `dataBytes` in Java.